# Are questions about specific tools also allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions

On a daily base I pretty much stumble upon questions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818514/monodevelop-code-window-colour-scheme). They are not about programming but about programming tools. Are these questions on-topic for stack overflow? Wouldn't they belong on superuser or so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a tool is primarily used for programming or by programmers, it's okay to ask about it on Stack Overflow. That leaves a lot of room for overlap with Super User on certain tools, like [notepad++](/questions/tagged/notepad%2b%2b) for one example, where questions could be asked on either site. Rule of thumb, if you're using a general-purpose tool for programming, it's probably okay to ask about it on SO.

---

I see a lot of tools questions break down when they're in one of two categories:

1. Asking for a tool recommendation.
2. Asking for a feature comparison of two similar tools.

These types of questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow, even if they are about programming tools. Programming tools questions need to be specific questions about how to use a tool, not about selecting what tool to use.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, questions about *specific* tools are allowed.

For example:

- [git](/questions/tagged/git)
- [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)
- [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse)

and many more...